# Verify that a user can only query his own data/information

Tags: database, session, web-applications, authentication

o/

I'm working on a smaller app, and its going pretty well so far. I talked with a friend about it and he suddenly made me realize something. How do i make sure a user is only able to query his own data from a Database in the cloud?

Its a very simple app, where you can create a user and make some personal shopping lists.

I thought about a couple of options, but I'm not sure what is the right direction to take - or even if any of them is the right one.

1. The username/id & password is stored locally and appended to the request, and checked against the DB every time.
2. A token is generated, saved both in the DB & stored locally as a "active" session, and every time a request is send, the token is appended to the request and checked.
3. ...?

I'm sorry if i placed this topic have the wrong tags, since i was not 100% sure where they should be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from your description it seams that you are working on a **"no backend"** app. If it is the case I suggest you to take a look to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) since it will solve all your concerns about authentication and user authorization.

If your would like to use a more custom approach, simply consider that appending the username and a passowrd to a request is always not recommended and since you are using a token is also unnecessary.

Now, returning to the question, i will give you my vision related to contexts where an authentication token is used and thus a backend is needed:

1. when you log-in a user, you produce a token that is function of the user id
2. each user request must contain that token
3. the backend can extract the id of the user that submitted the request from the appended token
4. a policy or a specific condition will check that data that is going to be retrieved must belong to the user whose id has been extracted.

Hope this could help you

Comment: I'm sure if i wasn't clear, i do idd have a backend DB. How do i make a token that the backend can get the id from? And dont i need to have a dynamic token, so that will update if the user havent been logged in for somet ime?

Comment: It depends on the technology stack you rely on. For example for NodeJS there is [PassportJS] (http://passportjs.org/), but usally this is a feature that a lot of frameworks offers